# OKHttp DNS lookup asynchronously

Tags: dns, okhttp

```
public class OkHttpDns implements Dns {
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public List<InetAddress> lookup(@NotNull String hostname) throws UnknownHostException {
        MyLookUpUtility.getInstance.lookup(hostname, new MyLookUpUtility.lookupCallback() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onlookupResponseSuccess(JSONObject nslookupResponseJSON) {
                Log.d("LookupResponse", nslookupResponseJSON.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onlookupResponseFailure(String errCode) {
                Log.d("LookupResponse", "Error Code : "+errCode);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In the above code, lookup method of DNS interface of OKHttp wants to return immediately. But my custom NSLookupUtility is an asynchronous call and I will have the ip address of the hostname only after a while. How to solve this problem? how to make the synchronous call to wait for the asynchronous call within it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public List<InetAddress> lookup(@NotNull String hostName) throws UnknownHostException {

        completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        performLookUp(hostName);
        try {
            String ipAddress = completableFuture.get();
            if (ipAddress != null) {
                List<InetAddress> inetAddresses = Arrays.asList(InetAddress.getAllByName(ipAddress));
                return inetAddresses;
            }
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error : ExecutionException : "+e );
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error : InterruptedException : "+e );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Dns.SYSTEM.lookup(hostName);
    }

    private void performLookUp(@NotNull String hostName) {
       MyUtiluty.getInstance().lookup(hostName,
                 new MyCallBack() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String ip) {
                            completableFuture.complete(ip);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(String errCode) {
                        completableFuture.complete(null);
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `CompletableFuture`. You’ll create an instance in `lookup()`, kickoff the async lookup, and then call `future.get()`. When your async call completes, call `future.complete()`.

Comment: Thanks. I used CompletableFuture to solve the problem. It worked. I will post what I did. It will help others.